# @for not showing correctly

Tags: html, angular, for-loop, angular17

Using the @for feature with a simple example iterating an array, it doesn`t show on the DOM. It just shows

tablero.component.html

```
<div class="tablero-body">
    <div class="tablero">
        <div></div>

        <ul>
            @for (color of colors; track color) {
                <li>{{ color }}</li>
            }
        </ul>
            
    </div>
</div>
```

tablero.component.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CeldaComponent } from '../celda/celda.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tablero',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CeldaComponent],
  templateUrl: './tablero.component.html',
  styleUrl: '../../../../../../front-end-shared/css/Game/Tablero/Tablero.css'
})

export class TableroComponent {
  colors = ["Red", "Blue", "White"];
}
```

DOM:

```
<div _ngcontent-ng-c3939563053="" class="tablero-body">
    <div _ngcontent-ng-c3939563053="" class="tablero">
         <div _ngcontent-ng-c3939563053=""></div>
         <ul _ngcontent-ng-c3939563053="">
               <!--container-->
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Guillermo Torres Are you trying to see the "Red", "Blue", "White" inside the DOM?, does you mean SSR?

Comment: Yes, with the @for I'm trying to create 3 <li> elements where each one has one of the names from the colors array. Like this:

<li> Red </li>
<li> Blue </li>
<li> White </li>.

I'm not sure what do you mean by SSR

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-itvyt9?file=src%2Fmain.ts) check, this is working?, may did you add some style?

Comment: I've noticed that when reloading the page, the list (<li> Red </li> <li> Blue </li> <li> White </li>) doesn't show up. However, when I interact with something on the page, such as a button, the three elements suddenly appear.

Comment: That's occurring by the change Detection of angular, so my advice try to add an 'if' is declared the colors array then do the 'for' may it helps to Angular to know when have to be display it.

Comment: i assume you are leaving out some important part of your code. If I try your code on stackblitz it works.

Comment: Unfortunately the if didn't work for me, but I found something interesting,the component "tablero" is used in a component called game-page (I didn't know it could be important sorry), the html of game-page is:
<app-tarjeta></app-tarjeta>
<app-chat></app-chat>
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
<app-tablero></app-tablero>
So when I put the <app-tablero></app-tablero> in the first or second place it works for example like this:
<app-tarjeta></app-tarjeta>
<app-tablero></app-tablero>
<app-chat></app-chat>
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>

Comment: If you know the reason I'd love to hear it but for now it works for me. Thank you